# javascript/jquery on-document-write event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I need to add event listeners to html elements with a `data-tooltip` attribute.

For elements that are present at page-load, I can do this in a `$(document.ready())` block.

Now if I dynamically add such an element to the page at "run-time", I have to manually add those event listeners to the element.

Is there a way I can listen to something like a *document-write* event (if such a thing exists) and add the event listeners from there ?

Comment: There's no such event, but it sounds like your problem can be easily solved by [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) (EDIT: which, since you're using jQuery, jQuery has quite a nice API for: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Sounds like a job for [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe)

Comment: @RobinZigmond got it. Solved with `$(document).on("mouseover", "[data-tooltip]", function(e){...});` Thanks :-)

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes.